# Postgres database restore with ignore errors

Tags: postgresql, restore

I have created a postgres database backup using pg_dump command - which created `.sql` file

I am trying to restore the database from this backup.  The original database name is called kstar and I want to restore it to a new database called rstar.

I created the new database first by using `create database rstar`, and used the following command :

```
psql -U postgres rstar < /home/ubuntu/bkup/kstar_Jun-13-2021.sql
```

The database is around 112 GB in size and it is critical for me to restore this database.  The above command creates all the tables and starts copying the data.  In one of the table which has a date column the data is in the backup for the date field is stored as `202` instead of `2021`, which throws the following error and stops the restoration.

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "202"
CONTEXT:  COPY r_2332, line 368225818, column date: "202"
```

Is it possible to ignore this error, skip and continue with copying the database?

The table schema for r_2332 is as follows:

```
                   Table "public.r_2332"
  Column   |       Type       | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------+------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 site_id   | integer          |           |          | 
 date      | date             |           |          | 
 hour      | integer          |           |          | 
 reach     | integer          |           |          | 
 maid      | text             |           |          | 
 latitude  | double precision |           |          | 
 longitude | double precision |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "date_pkey" btree (date)
    "hour_pkey" btree (hour)
    "maid_pkey  " btree (maid)
    "reach_pkey" btree (reach)
    "site_id_pkey" btree (site_id)
```

Comment: No `COPY` is all or none. Is column `date`(by the way not a good name) really a `date` type? If so '2021' would not work either.  If it is a `date` type field then '202' should not have got into it in the first place. You need to figure out how that happened and correct the data.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Quite disheartening....thank you anyway.

Comment: Not disheartening it is Postgres telling you that there is something wrong with your data. You need to figure out how  '202' got into a date type field? That should not happen and if  it did indicates some sort of issue that needs to be resolved.

Comment: I agree...but my condition is without restoring the db I would not be able to figure out..

Comment: Is the the database(kstar) you dumped it from still running? Or can you start it again?

Comment: No...the kstar is deleted.

Comment: Add the schema for table `r_2332`(I presume that is the correct one) to your question.

Comment: since the dump is in plain text, open the file and comment out line 368225818 ...

Comment: @JGH  THank you...since my file is around 113 GB I am not sure if my machine would support opening such a large file

Comment: There are some tools that won't open the entire file, just a portion of it.

Comment: `line 368225818,` : maybe the file was truncated? (disk full, or Windows)